# How to get max number in an array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays want to get index of each item in `array2` like below:

```
const array1 = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'mango', 'watermelon'];
const array2 = ['apple', 'orange', 'watermelon'];

const x = array2.map(item2 => array1.findIndex(item => item === item2 ));
console.log(Math.max(x)); // output: NaN
```

And then I am trying to get max number from `x` array but it output returned NaN. How can I get max number in this array?

Comment: `Math.max(...x)`

Comment: @Spectric  can you explain to me how the `Math.max()` works? Why we needs to use spread operator in this method?

Comment: `Math.max` returns the highest of the parameters. The spread operator expands the array into parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the spread operator

```js
const array1 = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'mango', 'watermelon'];
const array2 = ['apple', 'orange', 'watermelon'];

const x = array2.map(item2 => array1.findIndex(item => item === item2))

console.log(Math.max(...x))
```

This should do the trick because it will take the array elements and pass them as parameters to Math.max()